# Common callback for all instances of a class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a custom Javascript class that generates a JQuery mousedown callback. The mousedown callback is on $(document) and should really only be set for the first new instance, and not for any subsequent ones. I've got something like the following:

```
function myclass(arg){
   this.arg = arg;
   $(document).mousedown(function(down_event){
       // start action
   }).mouseup(function(){
      // stop action
      })
}
```

I'd like those callbacks to only register once in the event that multiple `myclass` instances are crated, and not at all if none are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a jQuery function for that. Use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind a handler to the first instance of an event raised on an element (in this case `document`).

```
function myclass(arg){
    this.arg = arg;
    $(document)
        .one('mousedown.yourEvent', downHandler)
        .one('mouseup.yourEvent', upHandler);
}

function downHandler(e) {
    // start action
}

function upHandler(e) {
    // stop action

    //ensure event dead forever
    $(document).on('.yourEvent', function() { return false; });
}
```

Updated. The changes (using named handlers rather than anonymous functions, putting events in a specific namespace) are to ensure that new instances of myclass don't rebind to the event if they are created after the first one has finished being unbound.

Comment: Just to clarify... `.one()` is not bound once, it's executed once. It's likely that if you create 15 instances of `myClass` that 15 anonymous functions are being bound to `document`, and that because of `.one()` the action can be executed up to 15 times before each instance is removed.... or maybe they all execute at once, but then never execute again.

Comment: @jwatts Thanks for the note, I made a few changes. I suppose my assumption was that these classes were all created before the first event was fired -- so that its implicit `unbind` would get rid of any other bindings, but you're right: an instance created after that click would likely have rebound to it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a variable to flag if the events have already been registered and register them only if they haven't already been registered.

An example of this:

```
var registered = false; // the 'flag' variable, default to false (i.e. not yet registered)

function myclass(arg){
   this.arg = arg;

   if (!registered) { // check the 'flag' variable if events have been registered yet
      registered = true; // set the 'flag' variable as events will be registered this time

      $(document).mousedown(function(down_event){
         // start action
      }).mouseup(function(){
         // stop action
      })
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of possible options.

Option 1: A global var

```
function myclass(arg){
   this.arg = arg;

   if (!window._myClassCreatedAlready) {
      $(document).mousedown(function(down_event){
          // start action
      }).mouseup(function(){
         // stop action
      })
   }
   window._myClassCreatedAlready = true;
}
```

Option 2: jQuery Data

```
function myclass(arg){
   this.arg = arg;

   if (!$.data(document, "mousedownset")) {
      $(document).mousedown(function(down_event){
          // start action
      }).mouseup(function(){
         // stop action
      })
   }
   $.data(document, "mousedownset", true);
}
```